# TvView with multiple SurfaceView

Tags: android, react-native, surfaceview, television

I am currently implementing TvView (same Basic player logic over it) I n react-native and I am wondering how to switch TvView to another Surface?

We have RN TV app, which implements several players for different platforms. Now we are implementing custom OEM Android TV system. One client has own player, which can play encrypted multicast, therefore he won't provide source code (TvInputService also closed, got only id). Instead of it, he provided custom TvView, which has some basic events and 'tune' method.

I wrote player integration to our system, but not finished it yet. All our players uses a SurfaceView for rendering. For players like ExoPlayer and MediaPlayer it is not such problem, because they are both implementing 'setSurfaceView' methods. I tried to figure out how it works, but I failed. I use Android for 1.5 week and I am not familiar with all those Android hacks. Can someone provide me a directions, where should I dig? Everything near SurfaceView in Threads, and I am a little bit scared)